# How to avoid blank first result when searching from databse

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have search webpage, but when the search is run, there is a blank first result.

```
<?php include "headnav.php";

$count = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lost_property";
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    $item = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, htmlspecialchars($_POST['item']));
    $area = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect, htmlspecialchars($_POST['area']));
    $sql = "
    SELECT * 
      FROM lost_property
      JOIN item 
        ON lost_property.itemID = item.itemID
      JOIN area 
        ON lost_property.areaID = area.areaID
     WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' 
       AND item LIKE '%$item%' 
       AND area LIKE '%$area%'
     ORDER 
        BY lost_property.name ASC
";
    $search_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($search_query);
}
$result = $dbconnect->query($sql);
?>

<body>
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Search for lost property here:</h1>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Name:
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
            Item type:
            <select name="item" class="dropdown">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Item</option>
                <?php
                $item_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT item FROM `lost_property`
                JOIN item ON (lost_property.itemID = item.itemID)
                ORDER BY item ASC
                ";

                $item_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $item_sql);
                $item_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_query);
                do {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $item_rs['item']; ?>"><?php echo $item_rs['item']; ?></option>
                <?php
                } while ($item_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_query));
                ?>
            </select>
            Area (where it was found):
            <select name="area" class="dropdown">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Area</option>
                <?php
                $area_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT area FROM `lost_property`
                JOIN area ON (lost_property.areaID = area.areaID)
                ORDER BY area ASC
                ";

                $area_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $area_sql);
                $area_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($area_query);
                do {
                ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $area_rs['area']; ?>"><?php echo $area_rs['area']; ?></option>
                <?php
                } while ($area_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($area_query));
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" name="btn">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <h2>Search results:</h2>
        <?php
        //check for results. If there are none display error
        if ($count < 1) {
        ?>
            <div class="error">
                <h1>No results were found.</h1>
            </div>
            <?php
        } //end if
        else {
            do {
            ?>
                <!-- display image and information from database and show in gallery  -->
                <div class="results">
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></h3>
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['item']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $search_rs['area']; ?></p>
                </div>
        <?php
            } // end of do
            while ($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
        } //end else
        //if there are any display
        ?>
    </div>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

It's hard to see without any CSS, but no matter what is searched, there is always one result, but the h3 and p fields don't have any content.  If there wasn't the no results error message it would pop up there too.  What is causing this first result?

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries. This is not how we sanitise data

Comment: it is peculiar to see a `do...while` loop for iterating a recordset rather then the more common `while(){}` type - any reason for that choice?

Comment: You should use `while(...) { ... }` instead of `do {..} while(...)`. If you use `do-while` the loop will always run at least once since the condition is checked after the loop, instead of before. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: Is there a record where `area` is empty? That would seem to be the most logical explanation

Comment: @BenHillier - The OP says there's always one blank row. That's because in a do-while loop, it will _always_ run the first loop, no matter what. It also does it before the condition (before $search_rs has been assigned with any data) which is why they always get a blank row.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yep! You're right!

Comment: From the teacher, will talk to him about how we should be doing it!

Comment: Do not use `htmlspecialchars()` on the data going into the database. You should use this function only when displaying in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `while (){}`, if you use do instead it will run once first (credit to Magnus Eriksson).

It ends up like

```
else {
            while ($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query)) {
            ?>
                <!-- display image and information from database and show in gallery  -->
                <div class="results">
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></h3>
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['item']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $search_rs['area']; ?></p>
                </div>
        <?php
            } // end of do
        } //end else
        //if there are any display
        ?>
```

instead of

```
else {
            do {
            ?>
                <!-- display image and information from database and show in gallery  -->
                <div class="results">
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['name']; ?></h3>
                    <h3><?php echo $search_rs['item']; ?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo $search_rs['area']; ?></p>
                </div>
        <?php
            } // end of do
            while ($search_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_query));
        } //end else
        //if there are any display
        ?>
```

Comment: Actually a `foreach` loop would be much simpler